# Finding data in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript object I am creating from a database call. It will have multiple items and I will need to be able to reference one by a specific key/value (moduleID).

```
success: function(data) {

        // Define our local vars
        var moduleIncludes = Array();

        // Loop over each of the users selected modules and put them into an array
        $(data).find('modules').each(function() {

            // Push module JS file names to an array
            moduleIncludes.push($(this).find('moduleJSFile').text());

            // Create an object of module data
            moduleData.push({
              moduleID: $(this).find('moduleID').text(),
              moduleRow: $(this).find('row').text(),
              moduleColumn: $(this).find('col').text(),
              moduleName: $(this).find('moduleName').text(),
              moduleDescription: $(this).find('moduleDescription').text(),
              moduleJSFile: $(this).find('moduleJSFile').text(),
              moduleIcon: $(this).find('moduleIcon').text(),
              moduleStartingXsize: $(this).find('startingXsize').text(),
              moduleStartingYsize: $(this).find('startingYsize').text(),
              moduleResizeLocked: $(this).find('resizeLocked').text(),
              moduleMinXsize: $(this).find('minXsize').text(),
              moduleMinYsize: $(this).find('minYsize').text()
            });
        });

        // Using our array of modules, fetch them to include them into the page
        $.getMultiScripts(moduleIncludes, 'includes/js/modules/').done(function() {
            // All of the modules have been included. Trigger the grid functionality.
            renderCanvas();
        });
    }
});
```

Instead of having to loop over each one to find what I am looking for, is there a way I can name the object by the `moduleID` instead since its unique?

For example, if I want to see all the data pertaining to moduleId 1, I would like to be able to just search the object by ID rather than loop it to find it.

Can I achieve this in my creation?

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of `data`'s format? If you have an array then you have to loop through it (or use `.find()` or `.filter()`), but if you have an object then you can refer to properties by key name.

Comment: Data is an XML string passed down from a stored procedure. The objects are being created fine as you can see in the image but I need to define them by ID somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe what you need is more like:

```
moduleIncludes = {};
moduleIncludes[Id] = {"moduleRow":$(this).find('row').text() ...};
```

doing like this, you'll be able to request a specific module directly from ID.

Comment: This is what I needed. Now I can say moduleIncludes[1].moduleRow

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` function for searching object.

Document in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp).

Example: Filter by object ID

```
function matchId(id) {
    return moduleData.moduleID == id;
}

data = moduleData.filter(matchId);
```

It is more simple than you write a loop with `for` or `foreach`.

Goodluck and have fun!